# What does "Puesto que..." mean?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Qué significa la frase *Puesto que* en la siguiente oración?

> *Puesto que los estudiantes han estado construyendo gráficas desde el preescolar, ellos rápidamente responden “¡hacer una gráfica!”*

---

What does the phrase *Puesto que* mean in the following sentence?

> *Puesto que los estudiantes han estado construyendo gráficas desde el preescolar, ellos rápidamente responden “¡hacer una gráfica!”*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means "since". *Puesto* is the past from *poner*, which in this context may be taken as a synonim to *given*. So *puesto que* is *given that*.

Comment: *Puesto* que is one of the many words used to connect case and effect *Puesto que + cause + (and usually a coma) + effect*. Words like *Debido a que, puesto que, a causa que, ahora que, gracias a, por culpa de, porque, ya que, pues* this are some spanish words and their [version in English](http://www2.elc.polyu.edu.hk/cill/exercises/cause&effect.htm) (not exactly the sames but just to make you an idea) would be these 
*because of, caused by, cause of, reason for, attributed to, on account of, owing to, given that, because*. I think both languages use it on similar contexts.